# Crystal Reports parameter returns a number ie 2000. How can I use a formula to count up by one

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to have a user enter a start Year for a report that will show 10 years of stats beginning from that start year.

I have a parameter where the user inserts the year (ie 2000) as the start year, but the parameter is just recognized as a number not as part of a date or year. Which I thought was fine (I have everything I want working in the report for the first year. Now that I want to go an add a section that takes the parameter and adds one, I'm having trouble.

DateAdd seems to just work with dates and this parameter is passed as a number. I must really be missing something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the code you are using? This will help narrow down where to focus

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Year({table.dateField}) IN {?YearPrompt} TO ({?YearPrompt}+1)
```